# MPMoviePlayerViewController not showing video only audio working in iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone-5

In `MPMoviePlayerViewController` only audio is working but video is not showing. It works in iphone 4, 4s etc with ios 8 and ios 7.

```
     NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://examplevideo.mp4"];
    self.playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self.playercontroller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
     self.playercontroller.contentURL = movieURL;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playercontroller.view];
   [self.playercontroller play];
```

Comment: it's working your code. there is no issue.... might be check your URL

Comment: its working in iphone 4,4s the issue is in iPhone5

Comment: I have check in iPhone 5 simulator ios 7.1.... issue on iPhone 5 Device ?

Comment: it will work in simulator, iPhone 5 device not working

Answer (score 0):

You should try to call `[self.playercontroller play]` after you have add the view to `self.view`, not before.